# Vuejs How to have many <a> tags and hashtags within <router-link> or @click function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVoxB.jpg)

i want to have a post card like twitter post card, if clicked on any part of the post card goes to post page, but when clicked on hashtags or links goes to the hashtag or link

example below
1.

```
<div @click="gotoPostPage" class="text-weight-light text-justify">
    {{ feed.content }}

    <a href="https://google.com">check google</a> if you need more information then follow @benny(a tag) or follow these hashtags
    #google #finda, #checks, now when i click within this post take me to post page
 
  </div>
```

now this hits the gotoPostPage function even if link or a tag is clicked

using this also
2.

```
 <router-link :to="`/post/${ feed.id }`">
    {{ feed.content }}

    <a href="https://google.com">check google</a> if you need more information then follow @benny(a tag) or follow
    these hashtags
    #google #finda, #checks, now when i click within this post take me to post page

  </router-link>
```

goes to   even when [check google](https://google.com) is clicked

Please how can i resolve this, your help is highly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@click.stop` to your links. E.g:

```html
<a href="https://google.com" @click.stop>check google</a>
```

This will stop propagation of `click` events to the parent DOM elements.

---

Note: `@click.stop` is shorthand for `@click="e => e.stopPropagation()"`.

[Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

---

Update, based on data shown in comment:

I would avoid storing HTML id database. That's a really bad pattern. You're supposed to detach the data from the UI layer. You have to allow the UI layer to change, based on device and medium. I'd try to store that data as `string`s holding a hashtag name and, where the name is different than the hastag, as on object, containing both.

Something like this:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, computed, onMounted, toRefs } = Vue;

createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      items: [],
      links: computed(() => state.items.map(
        item => ({
          name: item.name || `#${item}`,
          url: item.url || `/hashtag/${item}`
        })
      ))
    });
    
    onMounted(async() => {
      /* replace this promise with an axios call to server which returns
         an array, similar to the one i'm passing here:
         (see axios call example below)
       */
      const data = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve([
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'печаль',
            'грусть',
            { 
              name: '#mens',
              url: '/hashtag/fıstıklıbaklava'
            }, 
            'чайная',
            'джаз'
          ]);
        });
      })
      // example axios call:
      /*
         const data = await axios
           .get('http://endpoint-returning-data')
           .then(({data}) => data);
      */
      state.items = data;
      console.log('See difference betwen items (received from server) \r\n\and links (same data, mapped for template):\r\n', {...state}, '\r\nMakes sense?');
    })
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      log: () => console.log('You clicked on app!')
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="link in links" :key="link.url" @click="log">
    <a :href="link.url"
       v-text="link.name"
       @click.stop></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it produces the HTML from the data. The template also applies the `stopPropagation()`, in the `v-for`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works, but in my case the <a> is dynamic, will each <a tag coming from the database have @click on it?, or it there a way to do it better

Comment: Can you show me how your data looks like? When getting it from the database, what does it look like? It's likely an array of objects. You can iterate through it using `v-for` and you can place `@click.stop` on each item, inside the template.

Comment: okey so i have such data

Testing#one <a href="/hashtag/two">#two</a> <a href="/hashtag/three">#three</a>.test  but also with chineese <a href="/hashtag/печаль">#печаль</a> <a href="/hashtag/грусть">#грусть</a> <a href="/hashtag/fıstıklıbaklava">#mens</a> <a href="/hashtag/чайная">#чайная</a> <a href="/hashtag/джаз">#джаз</a>

will i have to put @click.stop on all <a tag

Comment: That data doesn't make any sense. It's neither valid HTML or a valid data structure. Can you update your question with the actual response you get from backend?

Comment: @BenjaminChuks, I added an example of how to do it. You need to replace the promise with an actual call returning a JSON array containing data with a structure similar to the one I showed in the example.